# Error:Could not find property 'semanticVersion' on root project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

My IntelliJ java Gradle project failed with the error.

> Error:Could not find property 'semanticVersion' on root project 'MY_PROJECT_NAME'.

It did not create src and other folders.

Comment: Please do not answer you question in the question. Instead, submit a self-answer

Comment: corrected, thanks @AndrewL.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error when trying to create a new Gradle Java project. After I have created project with auto folder generation option in IntelliJ wizard, I did not see any of the source or grade wrapper folders. Also, the project build failed everytime with error

> Error:Could not find property 'semanticVersion' on root project 'MY_PROJECT_NAME'.

The final solution was that there was no "gradle.properties" file in my project. After I have created a new file "gradle.properties" and added line 'semanticVersion=1.0.0' to it, everything worked fine. Hope this helps someone.